# Hibernate check if updating a record succeeded

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

I am creating a Jersey web service using Hibernate. One of the methods available is updating a record in the database which I'm doing like this:

```
private Boolean updateSingleRecord(Session session, Person updatedRecordData)
{
    try
    {
        short id = updatedRecordData.getPersonId();
        Person per = (Person) session.load(Person.class, id);
        per.setPersonEmail(updatedRecordData.getPersonEmail());
        per.setPersonMobile(per.getPersonMobile());
        transaction.commit(); //was defined earlier in the code
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The fields are define such that the mobile phone needs to have a unique value. If I update the object to an already existing value, I will not get any error, but the value simply won't be changed. How can I detect if a change was made after the commit without comparing the initial and new value?

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate Interceptor that would act like a trigger in the events like create, modify and update. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html so check that entity is modified and persisted.

You can make a new session-scope Interceptor in spring's implementation of Hibernate 4

```
 Session session = s.withOptions().interceptor(new MyInterceptor().openSession();
```

Comment: Did it clarify the situation?